# could gmapping pkg work in UWSim?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, uwsim, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,I am trying to do path planning using UWSim + RViz.And now there's something wrong with mapping.I followed some tutorials which is implemented by Gazebo+RViz and I also get the necessary lidar data through UWSim ROSInterfaces.However the map just won't come up.
[image: image description]

Here is the tf tree of the current master:
[image: image description]

Anyone know how I can fix this?Any answer would be of help!Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413194/could-gmapping-pkg-work-in-uwsim?/) by [marvelousluke](https://answers.ros.org/users/121802/marvelousluke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2023-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know Gmapping is designed for 2D occupancy grids, but your robot probably moves in 3D.

You need another SLAM tool to build 3D maps (e.g. octomaps), and again probably some dedicated tools to do path planning in such maps.

---

Originally posted by [Olivier Kermorgant](https://answers.ros.org/users/11856/olivier-kermorgant/) with karma: 280 on 2023-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marvelousluke](https://answers.ros.org/users/121802/marvelousluke/) on 2023-04-07**:
Thank you so much!